# Is there a way to use the docstring of a class member in a gui generated automatically?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm creating automatically some gui components to modify the members of a parameter classes.
As I have many of them, I'm trying to automatize the gui components creation as much as possible.

I was wondering if there were any way to use the docstring, for example defined with triple quoted string just after the variable declaration.

```
class Params:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter_1 = 'value1'
        """docstring 1"""
        self.parameter_2 = 'value2'
        """docstring 2"""

def get_widget(param):
    for name, value in vars(params):
        # create the gui component
        # but how to access "docstring 1 or 2" ???
```

In short, I would like to access the string `docstring 1` when generating the gui component, and use it as a show tip for example.

It seems that it would be the most efficient to get the doc to the gui, and keep the code documentation compact and synchronized with the gui.

Is that possible, good practice ? Are there other way to achieve the same goal ?

Thanks

Comment: Python has no concept of attribute docstrings. Some external tools recognize such docstrings, but Python itself doesn't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use properties. Properties contain a getter, a setter, a deleter, and a docstring.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Docstring goes here."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Then you will have a docstring belonging to C.x:

```
>>> C.x.__doc__
Docstring goes here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would do the trick... except for the compactness! (14 lines for each parameter)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [an xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Better define parameters as plain objects/namedtuples  or as a dict/list/tuple.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.parameter_1 = {value: 'value', hint: 'hint about param'}
    self.parameter_2 = ('value', 'hint')
    self.parameter_3 = Parameter(value='value', hint='hint') #assuming you've defined Parameter = namedtuple('Parameter', ['value', 'hint'])
```

Comment: I don't think it is a xy problem. Python is full of syntaxic sugar. I was trying to find one to avoid using a dict or a specific class for parameter, which makes things more verbose when you want to access the value, more complex type hint,